# Linking inside of pattern rules

Tags: makefile

I have a generic build system that I import as a Git submodule into my projects, each of which has a wrapper makefile that includes the build system's makefile. Suppose I have something like the following in the build system's makefile:

```
$(BIN_DIR): | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

And prerequisites like the following in the projects' makefiles:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/foo: $(FOO_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%)
```

While this technique works well for libraries, it obviously doesn't work well for executables, because each needs to be linked with a different set of libraries. So my question is how to achieve that **without relying of *GNU Make*-specific features**? With *GNU Make*, I could do something like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR): | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $((nodir $(basename $@))_LINK:%=-l %)
```

```
foo_LINK = mylib1 mylib2

$(BIN_DIR)/foo: $(FOO_OBJ_FILES:%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%)
```

One portable solution that I've thought of but would rather not use because it's a huge hack, is to have a *.link* file associated with each executable, containing one line like this: `-l mylib1 -lmylib2` and then do something like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR): | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< `cat $@.link`
```

So, all these things aside, I need to somehow magically pass the correct set of libraries to the pattern rule or to have a variable expand to the correct set of libraries when the pattern rule gets executed.

Any ideas? Thanks.

PS: I know this seems like more trouble than it's worth but I've simplified things for the purpose of this question. In reality, it saves me from dealing with some pepetition, not just saving me one line.

Comment: Err... order-only prerequisites and pattern rules are both GNU make specific features.  So I don't understand why you you say you can't use them.  If you really can't use any GNU make features then you can't include `|` in your prerequisites list at all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've come up with an answer:

```
$(BIN_DIR): | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $($(F)_LINK:%=-l %)
```

```
foo_LINK = mylib1 mylib2
```

Unfortunately, while there is a proposal for adding nested/computed variables into *POSIX make* for Issue 8 of the specification, it seems to have been in limbo for the past 10 years or so.

Comment: Order-only prerequisites (`|`) are a GNU make-only feature.  Patterns (`%` chars) in a substitution reference are not part of the standard (using them leads to unspecified behavior).

Comment: Actually, they're all coming to Issue 8 of POSIX. Just not the nested variables, most likely. I've been trying to push for them on their bug tracker.

Comment: Order-only?  In POSIX?  I've not heard anything like that and I've never heard of this feature available in any other version of make.  Usually POSIX won't standardize something unless it's already widely available.  Do you have an issue # from the Austin group regarding this addition?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Christmas was busy :) You are right, order-only prerequisites are *not* coming to POSIX. I went through the tickets myself.